# JSONP with Spring 3.0 and Jackson

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsonp, jackson

To return a JSON response with Spring 3.0 is enough to add a `@ResponseBody` annotation along with the `@RequestMapping` inside a `@Controller`. Provided that MapppingJacksonJson library is loaded and that the client sends Accept header with `application/json`, it will work.

What about JSONP? Is it possible to return it and how?

Comment: See Jeremy Grelle's answer on [this blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/#comment-171228). Here's [another tutorial](http://jpgmr.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/tutorial-implementing-a-servlet-filter-for-jsonp-callback-with-springs-delegatingfilterproxy/).

Comment: I had to finish all the services before passing to JSONP mapping, I've followed "another tutorial", it was a no brainer step by step handholding and most of all it worked. The only problem is the lack of sanitation of the callback parameter, but I will handle that. Thanks!

Comment: @stivlo can you share your solution? What is "another tutorial" that you used?

Comment: @user1647708 In the answer above there are two links, one is called "this blog post", the other "another tutorial".

Comment: 2nd link is dead...

Answer (score 12):

This blog post shows a correct and compact solution: [Implementing JSONP in Spring MVC 3.0.x](http://vivin.net/2011/07/01/implementing-jsonp-in-spring-mvc-3-0-x/)

This one works better for Spring 3.1: [XML, JSON, JSON-P Web Service Endpoints in Spring 3.1](http://www.iceycake.com/2012/06/xml-json-jsonp-web-service-endpoints-spring-3-1/)

For Spring 3.2, here is a Jackson2 based JSONP converter:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

public class MappingJackson2JsonpHttpMessageConverter
    extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        JsonEncoding encoding = getJsonEncoding(outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType());
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = this.getObjectMapper().getFactory().createJsonGenerator(outputMessage.getBody(), encoding);        

        try {
            String jsonPadding = "callback";            

            // If the callback doesn't provide, use the default callback
            if (object instanceof IJsonpObject) {
                String jsonCallback = ((IJsonpObject)object).getJsonCallback();
                if (jsonCallback != null) {
                    jsonPadding = jsonCallback;
                }
            }            

            jsonGenerator.writeRaw(jsonPadding);
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw('(');
            this.getObjectMapper().writeValue(jsonGenerator, object);
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw(");");
            jsonGenerator.flush();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not write JSON: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

To add it, put this bean in your configuration:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class MyWebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters( List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters ) {
        MappingJackson2JsonpHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2JsonpHttpMessageConverter();

        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes( Lists.newArrayList(
            new MediaType( "application", "x-javascript" ),
            new MediaType( "application", "javascript" ),
            new MediaType( "text", "javascript" )
        ) );

        converters.add( converter );
    }

}
```

Comment: You could mitigate against [Rosetta Flash](http://miki.it/blog/2014/7/8/abusing-jsonp-with-rosetta-flash/) by adding jsonGenerator.writeRaw("/**/"); right above this line: jsonGenerator.writeRaw(jsonPadding);

Comment: You could overwrite writeInternal as:
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
    {
        MappingJacksonValue mjv = new MappingJacksonValue(object);
        mjv.setJsonpFunction("callback");
        
        super.writeInternal(mjv, outputMessage);
    }

Comment: @mickeymoon: Only if you use Spring 4.1. My answer is for Spring 3.2.

Answer (score 12):

Since `Spring 4.1` you can easy do it this way:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/endpoint")
    MappingJacksonValue getData(@RequestParam String callback) {
        MappingJacksonValue value = new MappingJacksonValue(new MyPojo());
        value.setJsonpFunction(callback);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a simpler, OOB approach for JSONP approach (JSONP/CORS should be built-in IMO...not require any custom code)...never found any...but after reaching out with the Spring team, it turns out that [JSONP is now supported OOB in 4.0.5 via `MappingJacksonJsonView`](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8346) and built-in supportCORS to follow later.