# how to register multiple conversion services under annotation-driven?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws

I have a custom conversion service factory extends `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`, so that it become a general conversion service for the controller:

```
<bean class="com.app.me.ExtendedConversionFactoryBean" id="generalConversionService" />
```

and

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="generalConversionService" />
```

everything is good, until I have to register another conversion service bean for JSONP in regards of REST service, like from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655975/jsonp-with-spring-3-0-and-jackson) thread, in the example there should be a message conversion service, under mvc:annotation-driven as well:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="com.iceycake.spring.jsonp.MappingJacksonJsonpHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>application/x-javascript</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

So may question is, can I set more than one  bean under same mvc config so above two conversion service can still live together or I should put the message conversion service and general conversion service in a service list bean? so say in other words, can I register both bean to the same mvc configuration

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="generalConversionService" />

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="com.app.myapp.MessageConvertionService">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>application/x-javascript</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

the requirement is pretty much to integrate the Formatters and HttpMessageConverters together in [this](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/21/spring-3-1-m1-mvc-namespace-enhancements-and-configuration) post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood properly, but if you are worried about repeating `mvc:annotation-driven`

The proper configuration should be

```
<bean class="com.app.me.ExtendedConversionFactoryBean" id="generalConversionService" />

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="generalConversionService">
    <mvc:message-converters  register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="com.iceycake.spring.jsonp.MappingJacksonJsonpHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>application/x-javascript</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Set *register-defaults* to *false* if you don't won't to include the default message converters. Adding multiple Message converte beans inside *message-converters* element is perfectly valid as well

Comment: Thanks. It looks your configuration put generalConversionService on top so all message converters must relate to generalConversionService as well?