# Can't make JSONP call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

this problem is really driving me crazy... I have 2 java web application: appA that publish a REST service which returns some object (which contains an image) in json format, and appB that consumes the service and shows the image. In my local machine it works (though I see the CORS error) but now I'm using a web environment (Layershift) and I'm getting an error "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://app-demo.j.layershift.co.uk/myservice/get/c80e9306105f4448?callback=myCallback&_=1477167892656"

I've been reading lot of examples of CORS and JSONP but I can't find what's wrong with my code, can anybody give a hint?

Controller in appA:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
@RequestMapping(value="/myservice/get/{somevar}")
public @ResponseBody MyObject getMyObject (@PathVariable String somevar, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    //some logic
    return obj;
}
}
```

ControllerAdvice in appA:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {
public JsonpAdvice() {
    super("myCallback");
}
}
```

javascript code with jsonp call in appB:

```
(function($) {
function myCallback(data) {
    if (data.status == "OK") {
        //shows the image contained
    }
}

$.fn.callWithJsonP = function(somevar) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "myservice/get/" + somevar,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "myCallback"
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Any help would be appreciated, regards

PS: also tried adding the directive "Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"" in Apache, but same result.

Comment: A 404 means you're trying to access an endpoint that doesn't exist. Are you sure you have the right URL?

Comment: Hi @JoeAttardi, yes, the URL is correct

Comment: Why are you using `jsonp` are they on different domain? also I think the ajax url need to be have a starting `/` for example `/"myservice/get/" + somevar`. Need to see `applicationContext`

Comment: Hi @user2181397, yes, they're in a different domain. And regarding the ajax URL, I've changed it so I can post it here, but in my real application it contains the full URL of the other web application

Comment: If you're getting a 404, then the URL isn't correct.

Comment: A proxy or a .htaccess rule may somehow block the ajax call thus resulting in a 404 error.

Comment: Mmmm... @JoeAttardi regarding the URL, http://app-demo.j.layershift.co.uk/myservice/get/c80e9306105f4448 exists in my application, but the "_" in the final attribute is added by jquery (I suppose), in all the examples I've seen, none of them added such a parameter

Comment: That's a cache-buster, it shouldn't cause a problem like this.

Comment: Going to the URL without the cache buster still gets an error. It says "OOOPS! No such environment"

Comment: Hi @Barmar, right now the application is not deployed, I had to remove it from Layershfit, the error is from previous executions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally can make the JSONP call, didn't solve my problem, but I'm able to make the call, so I'll post the changes.

First of all, in the main controller I'm not using @ResponseBody, I've changed it like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/myservice/get/{somevar}")
    public MappingJacksonValue getMyObject (@RequestParam String callback, @PathVariable String somevar, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        //some logic
        MappingJacksonValue value = new MappingJacksonValue(obj);
        value.setJsonpFunction(callback);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Notice the return type is MappingJacksonValue (thanks to [JSONP with Spring 3.0 and Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655975/jsonp-with-spring-3-0-and-jackson/26372645#26372645)), and the javascript code is this:

```
$.fn.callWithJsonP = function(somevar) {
    var url = "/myservice/get/" + somevar + "?callback=myCallback";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        if (data.value.status == "OK") {
            //show the image contained
        }
    });
}
```

There was no need to define a function called "myCallback". I've tested in my local machine and it is working.

Thanks everybody for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to perform a JsonP ajax call using Jquery. 
E.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/ny-app/getJSfunction",
    jsonp: "myfunctionName",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: soomedata,
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

Handle this call on the server side, and return a function encapsulated javascript code that returns some data. The returned javascript will look like this:

```
function myfunctioname(){
     // some code
     return 'whatever you want' ;
}
```

JQuery ajax will automatically execute the returned javascript function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: He's getting a 404 error because the URL is wrong. How is this relevant?

Comment: Thanks @DragoRaptor, but is the "success" function necessary? Shouldn't be called "myfunctionName" instead of "success", according to your definition?